# Drag zoomed texture view android

Tags: android, pinchzoom, textureview

I am Implementing pinch zoom on some video. For this i use many techniques but with no luck. I am using texture View as texture view support matrix transformations .  I am able to zoom and pinch . But now problem is that how can  I apply drag to zoomed view. Below is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.text.TextureActivity" >

    <com.text.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vvs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity code

```
public class TextureActivity extends Activity {

    private VideoView vv;
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_texture);

        vv = (com.text.VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvs);

        vv.setVideoPath("/storage/sdcard0/QieZi/videos/WhatsApp Video/VID-20150705-WA0000.mp4");
        vv.start();

        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,
                new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    private float focusX;
    private float focusY;

    private float lastFocusX = -1;
    private float lastFocusY = -1;

    static final int IMG_WIDTH = 640;
    static final int IMG_HEIGHT = 480;

    static final int IMAGE_X_POS = 560;
    static final int IMAGE_Y_POS = 20;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {


        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            focusX = detector.getFocusX();
            focusY = detector.getFocusY();

            if (lastFocusX == -1)
                lastFocusX = focusX;
            if (lastFocusY == -1)
                lastFocusY = focusY;

            mPosX += (focusX - lastFocusX);
            mPosY += (focusY - lastFocusY);
            Log.v("Hi Zoom", "Factor:" + mScaleFactor);
            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 2.0f));

            lastFocusX = focusX;
            lastFocusY = focusY;
            matrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            vv.setMatrix(matrix);


            vv.setTransform(matrix);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Video View Code is : http://pastebin.com/gDdGwNLT

Please help me.. I am in big trouble.

Comment: nobody knows what `com.text.VideoView` is

Comment: I added code , please check

Comment: if you want to translate your `VideoView` (drag) call `postTranslate` on your `Matrix`